# Import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, project, google-play-services, google-play-games

This code is from the original android developers page:

```
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils;
```

But in the project BaseGameUtils is not a class "BaseGameUtils" [image]

Our project BaseGameUtils was downloaded from this link, because the original one caused errors. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwANZFc0H24cOWlNRFlaOGtLbnc/edit

Comment: I can see it [on Github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameUtils.java) though...

Comment: Export BaseGameUtils as library, you need all proyecta in one workspace